# How do I declare a freemarker macro/function to be used within a few ajax views?

Tags: freemarker

I currently have a <#macro format_phone phone> within my code, and a few different pages use it.  How could I make this function be available to many pages?  ie. globally.  Currently it's copied and pasted, breaking the DRY principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in a `macros.ftl` file, `<#import "macros.ftl" as m>`, and then `<@m.format_phone phone>`